# Excel - Finding nth largest value with duplicate data

Tags: excel, duplicates, max

I have a the following table, it has more columns and is 40 rows long 
but this is an example of the data.  The table is sorted by Team #

Data Table

[image]

I am trying to create a 2nd table that shows the top 10 teams that
delivered gears.  I want to do this for the other columns as well.
I am trying to do this without VBA.
I used this function and it worked well:

```
=INDEX(TT_Team,MATCH(LARGE(TT_Tele_Gears,$A3),TT_Tele_Gears,0))
```

The problem is the duplicate data for the amount of gears delivered
IF two teams have delivered the same number of gears I want to show
them both, but do not care about which is #1 or #2
Currently I get this:

Top 10 Table

[image]

Any ideas on a fix ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could add 1/10000th of the row to the values. This should be small enough to "not see the change" but big enough so excel will line up the numbers from the bottom row to the top one for a "draw". Should work as array formula if you change your `MATCH(LARGE(TT_Tele_Gears,$A3),TT_Tele_Gears,0)` part to `MATCH(LARGE(TT_Tele_Gears+ROW(TT_Tele_Gears)/10000,$A3),TT_Tele_Gears+ROW(TT_Tele_Gears)/10000,0)`. And yes: that is a very dirty way to do it :P

Answer (score 2):

You could try a solution like this:

[image]

The formula in F2 copied down is just:

`=LARGE(B$2:B$12,D2)`

and in E2 as shown it's this:

`=INDEX(A$2:A$12,LARGE(IF(B$2:B$12=F2,ROW(B$2:B$12)-ROW(B$2)+1),COUNTIF(F2:F$6,F2)))`

confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copy down

It's the `COUNTIF` part at the end that makes the difference. This is counting from the current row, so for duplicates as you go down the column the `COUNTIF` value changes, so you get each duplicate