# Find The Highest Value And Return Adjacent Cell Value with duplicates In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an excel with below table

A      B 
Name Score 
A   80  
B   45  
C   34  
D   45  
E   99  
F   99  
G   99

In the above table E, F and G's scores are same (sharing the maximum value).

I am trying to achieve the Top 3 'Names' and hence trying the formula -

Max 2nd =`INDEX(A1:A8,MATCH(LARGE(B1:B8,2),B1:B8,1))`

Max 3rd =`INDEX(A1:A8,MATCH(LARGE(B1:B8,3),B1:B8,1))`

However, I am getting the FIRST name's 'E' only for the rest of the maximum. values.
I am expecting F and G to be displayed the next.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882196/excel-finding-nth-largest-value-with-duplicate-data

Answer (score 3):

You will need a list of the scores that you can increase the LARGE's *k* parameter using COUNTIF. This can be something as simple as the following in an unused cell and filled down,

```
=large(b$2:b$8, row(1:1))
```

Now use this formula beside the list you just created and fill down.

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(B$1:B$8=E2), COUNTIF(E$2:E2, E2)))
```

[image]